# Calling inherited method in included module

Tags: ruby, module

Suppose I have

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
    some_method
  end
  def self.some_method
    one_other_method
  end
end

class A < B 
  include Mod
end
```

Suppose `one_other_method` is some method of `B` class. I get an error message. How can I call `one_other_method` from `Mod` without getting this error?

Comment: I assume `one_other_method` is a class (not instance) method of `B`, in which case the only explanation for the error message is that `self` is not class `A` when `one_other_method` is called.  So what is `self`?  By inserting `puts` statement at the beginning of `self.included` and `self.some_method`, you will learn the following: `self in included = Mod`, `self in some_method = Mod`.  @Arup has explained how to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 5):

For that you need to change the design a bit :

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
      some_method(base)
  end
  def self.some_method(base)
      base.new.one_other_method
  end
end

class A < B 
  include Mod
end
```

Or you could do as

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
      base.new.some_method
    end
  def some_method
      one_other_method
  end
end

class A < B 
  include Mod
end
```

The point is - If you define the method as below

```
  def self.some_method(base)
      base.new.one_other_method
  end
```

`some_method` will be only restricted to the module `Mod`, as module singleton methods are not shared to the class(s)/module(s), where you would include it. That's the reason, you need to think it differently. I don't know your ultimate design goal, so I can't tell you what would be more suitable for you, rather I would say you, these are 2 approaches I am aware of.

Now if you define -

```
def some_method
  one_other_method
end
```

`some_method` will be available as instance method to `A`, and on the other hand as you did `class A < B ..`, `one_other_method` is also available as instance method to `A`. Thus, any one of the 2 can call other within them happily, without an explicit receiver, as `self` will be set by *Ruby* itself for you.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thank you but I have a problem because `one_other_method`returns some data that was added for the instantiation of `A` (when the module gets first included). Here you propose to call some new instance of `A`, is it possible to get these data ?

Comment: @user1611830 we will discuss on chat... brb 30 mins.. As I told design need to check :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit +1 for second approach. That is much much better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have fun, you can also check [`super_module`](https://github.com/AndyObtiva/super_module):

```
require 'super_module'
module Mod
  include SuperModule

  def self.some_method
    one_other_method
  end

  some_method
end

class A < B 
  include Mod
end
```

Comment: Interesting, and good to know, Marc-André.  You might want to show `require 'super_module'`.

Comment: Sure. Pro tip though: use `bundler`! :-)

Comment: Not being a pro, I haven't used it, but it's now on my to-do list. Thanks.